# CometD demo on JBoss 6

Tags: jboss6.x, server-push, cometd

I am planning to use Cometd library in my application that runs on JBoss AS 6. Therefore I downloaded cometd 2.4.0 and tried to deploy example war (from cometd-demo/target) to my AS. I was aware that this was not possible without modifications, so I did the changes in web.xml:

1. Changed to servlet 3.0 in web-app tag (it is originally 2.5). Used complete tag from [CometD faq answer](http://cometd.org/node/106). Also uncommented continuation filter that was already in web.xml, based on [this description](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/howtos/servlet-containers)
2. Based on [faq answer](http://cometd.org/node/106), added async-supported tag. However, this causes problems: if I just uncomment it, web.xml can't be parsed. I found out that this is due to order of tags in XML, so moved **async-supported** tag down the order, just after **load-on-startup** tag. However, Jboss still throws exceptions:

> ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/cometd-demo-2.4.0].[cometd]]
>   Servlet.service() for servlet cometd threw exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The servlet or filters that are being
>   used by this request do not support async operation
>
> ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/cometd-demo-2.4.0].[cometd]]
>   Servlet.service() for servlet cometd threw exception:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection from
>   BaseClassLoader@12a54b

Complete web.xml file that I use is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bz3iqOj-FxK9QTZ3ckl5RUxSRTJTVXFFd3hSSkNLQQ).

Example runs no my Jboss despite all errors reported, but by watching firebug, I can see that it does quick pooling instead of long pool. It seems that server thinks that browser has multiple connections open, which is not the case (see JSON below):

```
[{"id":"137","successful":true,"advice":{"interval":2000,"reconnect":"retry","multiple-clients":true,"timeout":20000},"channel":"/meta/connect"}]
```

Did anyone managed to make examples work with JBoss as6 and how? What I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

remove:

```
<!-- Portability Filter, needed only to run on non Jetty or non Servlet-3.0 containers -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

from web.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup and the same problem even if I remove continuation filter from web.xml.

I've found a thread on cometd-users group complaining about multiple-client issue on Tomcat 7 and the cause seems to be a Tomcat bug around Content-Type that is not set to "application/json".
However I've inspected packets and on JBossAS6 the content-type is correctly set on server responses.

**UPDATE**

I've give a try using Jetty 7 and the problem disappeared. The "multiple-clients" issue affects Tomcat as well as JBoss6 AS